# Select value associated with the latest date in a timeframe

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, sublist, array-formulas

I'm having trouble developing an Excel formula that can select the latest date in a given time period. If I had this in Excel:

```
Date         | Value  
Jan 1 2015   | 8  
Jan 26 2015  | 6   
Feb 24 2015  | 3   
Mar 22 2015  | 7  
April 2 2015 | 8  
April 9 2015 | 9
```

I'd want a formula that could pick out the latest date between `Jan 1 2015` and `March 31 2015` (so `March 22 2015`) and then give it's value (`7`).

The second part is easy I think using VLOOKUP, but the first part I'm confused about.  I've thought about having multiple nested IF statements but with a lot of entries that seems too time intensive.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this regular formula (no ctrl+alt+enter necessary), adjust ranges to suit:

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(INDEX((A2:A7>=--"1/1/2015")*(A2:A7<=--"3/31/2015")*A2:A7,)),A2:B7,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate max date in a range with the following array formula:

```
=MAX(IF((A2:A10>=startDate)*(A2:A10<=endDate),A2:A10)
```

Replace `A2:A10` with your range, and enter dates. Confirm with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Answer (score 1):

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(A:A*(A:A>=DATE(2015;1;1))*(A:A<DATE(2015;3;31)));A:B;2;FALSE)
```

and hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

A:A is the column with dates
B:B is the column with values

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MAX(IF(A:A<42094,A:A)),A:A,0))
```

with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Example shows `Jan 1 2015` (thank you for disclosing the month/day convention) but to avoid an incorrect return where the latest available date is earlier than the timeframe start:

```
=INDEX(B1:B11,MATCH(MAX(IF(A1:A11<42094,IF(A1:A11>42005,A1:A11)),0),A1:A11,0))
```

(also an array formula, whose range has been restricted to reduce the risk of delays).

1900 date system.